# How to echo lang('my_translated_string'); using anchor tag in CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, internationalization, anchor, echo

I am using **internationalization i18n class** and wondering **how could I echo my translated text for my menu items, from my language files using anchor tag** provided by CodeIgniter.

E.g. this works for both of my languages correct:

```
<a href="http://example.com"><?php echo lang('link_to_example_com'); ?></a>
```

And it is translated correctly using English language files when I am on /en or German when on /de

but this is not working:

```
<?php
$translated_text = lang('link_to_example_com');
echo anchor('http://example.com', $translated_text);
?>
```

How to use anchor in this case with a variable or lang function?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What does it mean *"this is not working"*? What error does it show?
Are you using it in view or in controller?
Are you loading URL helper `$this->load->helper('url');` in your controller?